# Vim pastes a random amount of lines each time

Tags: unix, vim

I often copy/paste several thousand lines of numbers into vim perfectly fine using the regular putty terminal. However, if I use another version of putty (with the same settings) or MobaXterm, Vim will only paste a random number of lines each time before it stops. Does anyone know why this could be happening, I tried playing with all the settings. I am running on a UNIX environment.

Comment: I do not believe that you're running `mobaxterm` on a UNIX environment.  Vim interprets all several keys in insert mode as commands, notably `<esc>` and `<c-o>` if your terminal encoding does not match the windows encoding such codes can be sent.  You will need to find a small verifiable example for anyone to be able to help you but I strongly suspect windows "smart quotes": „ ¨ ‚ ´ ‘ ’ “ ” (here encoded in utf-8 for easy reading)

Comment: it's probably not vim's fault, but the terminal clipboard size might be limited.